# How to return HTML to view via AJAX?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, datatables

I've got a view with a JQuery DataTable that loads it's content via AJAX by calling an action method (server-side processing) that returns a nice JSON string with all the data.

What I'm doing is the following:

1. I create a List that contains the data for the DataTable. Each row in the table is a string array because that's a requirement for DataTables.
2. I put all the data for the DataTable in an anonymous object. This data consists of the amount of rows, the data (the List) and some other stuff.
3. A JSON string is created from this anonymous object so all data is returned in JSON format
4. Some magic happens and the data is displayed in my DataTable.

The problem is: I can't output HTML because Razor automatically escapes this. I already tried stuff like Html.Raw, new HtmlString() and stuff like that, but the problem is: I HAVE to put HTML strings in my List collection because DataTables can't handle any other types as far as I know.

The DataTable in my view doesn't contain any definition of what columns should be rendered, this is done automatically by just looping through my JSON string (with Javascript or whatever) and displaying it (again, with Javascript).

So the question is: how can I render HTML in my DataTable when using MVC3 server-side processing?

BTW, the code:

```
<table id="datatable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Destination address</th>
            <th>Platform</th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tabledata">
    <!-- Content will be rendered here by AJAX -->
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Destination address</th>
            <th>Platform</th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

And the server-side processing:

```
public JsonResult List()
{
    List<PushApplication> pushApplications = _service.GetData(Request).ToList();

    int totalRecords = _service.GetApplicationCount();

    // Reformat the data.
    List<string[]> aaData = new List<string[]>(pushApplications.Count);
    aaData.AddRange(pushApplications.Select(application => new[]
    {
        application.Id.ToString(),
        application.Name, 
        application.DestinationAddress,
        application.Platform,
        "<a href='/PushApplication/Edit/" + application.Id + "'>Modify</a>",
        "<a href='/PushApplication/Delete/" + application.Id + "'>Delete</a>"
    }));

    // Construct anonymous object for the data table.
    var data = new { sEcho = Request.QueryString["sEcho"], iTotalRecords = totalRecords, iTotalDisplayRecords = totalRecords, aaData = aaData };

    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I invoke the datatable with the following bit of Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var oTable = $('#datatable').dataTable({
        "bPaginate": true,
        "bLengthChange": true,
        "bFilter": true,
        "bSort": true,
        "bInfo": true,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "iDisplayStart": 0,
        "sEcho": 1,
        "sDom": 'T<"clear"><"top"fi>rt<"bottom"pl><"clear">',
        "sAjaxSource": '/PushApplication/List',
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "fnServerData": fnDataTablesPipeline,
        "oTableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "/Plugins/TableTools/swf/copy_cvs_xls_pdf.swf"
        },
        "aoColumns": [
            { sWidth: '10%' },
            { sWidth: '30%' },
            { sWidth: '30%' },
            { sWidth: '30%' }
        ]
    });

    $("#submitForm").click(function () {
        oTable.fnDraw();
    });
});
```

Comment: can you post bit of javascript code too

Comment: Well, the magic is done by JQuery DataTables, the only thing I have to do is to include the library in my HTML and the <tbody id="tabledata"> will automatically be filled with data. I honestly don't know what part of that >7000 lines of code file is responsible for rendering the data.

I have however posted the javascript code that calls the JQuery DataTable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I misunderstood with my first reply, so apologies if you've already read it:

Are you trying to add HTML into some cells or rows? For example, adding a button that will have extended functionality?

The best way to do this isn't in the JSON (although it's certainly possible with other frameworks) it's in the DataTables callbacks. If you want to affect individual rows or cells within the row, go for `fnRowCallback` which I have used to add any number of extra widgets and markup to my cells.

[update follows]

From the DataTables website (http://datatables.net/ref#fnrowcallback) here's how you would do it with a 2D array:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
            /* Bold the grade for all 'A' grade browsers */
            if ( aData[4] == "A" )
            {
                $('td:eq(4)', nRow).html( '<b>A</b>' );
            }
            return nRow;
        }
    } );
} );
```

Further explanation of the sample: the callback accepts a few different objects, including nRow which is an object instance of the current row, and aData which corresponds to the aaData being sent back by the server side. It's a simple if statement: if there is the string "A" in the 5th column of data, go to the 5th column inside of nRow object and change its HTML so that instead of "A" it's a bolded "A". At the end of the callback, nRow is returned back, in its now-modified state.

You're not limited by 2D arrays of course. If you're using key-value pairs in a 3D object, you might look for something like `aData["someLabel"]` to modify. And the columns don't need to correspond; in the example they're both column 5, but you can do whatever you want. Or if you want to modify the row itself, you can do that, too, instead of looking for a particular `td` inside of `nRow`.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into that. I'm indeed trying to add HTML to cells in the datatable (a hyperlink in this case).

Do you have any code examples of how to add HTML to a row with fnRowCallBack?

Comment: Right on! I found it took a little bit of time investment to get up and running with DataTables, but once I started I discovered the API to be so rich that I can't imagine using something else. And I only use maybe 1/5 of its API.

Comment: I think I read somewhere in passing that you no longer need to return the row. Not sure why, but you could always look into it. On the other hand, returning nRow isn't going to hurt anything I don't imagine.

Answer (score 0):

What about using the append() function of JQuery?  Something roughly like...

```
function fillTable(data) {
    var r = new Array(), j = -1;
    $('#datatable tbody:gt(0)').empty();
    var html = '<tbody>';
    for (var key = 0, size = data.length; key < size; key++) {
        var row = '<tr>';
        row += '<td>' + data[key].Application.Id + '</td>';
        row += '<td class="account-field">' + data[key].Application.Name + '</td>';
        //keep adding here
        row += '</tr>'

        html += row;
    }
    html += '</tbody>';
    $('#datatable').append(html);

};
```

Comment: Using the DataTable plugin means that creating the HTML for a table is not necessary and won't really work. DataTables takes care of all of this.